# "~/" not returning full root path

Tags: asp.net, html

Everything that I've found online has said that "~/" will return the full application root for a URL, so `~/test.aspx` in a `test` subfolder would return `http://domain.com/test/test.aspx`. I can't figure out why then, this is not the way the tilde is being handled in our web application. In our case, the tilde is only returning the site root (so in the above example, we're getting `http://domain.com/test.aspx`).

Our tags do include `runat="server"`.

I've got to be missing something, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Is the root of the web aplication / or /test?

Comment: Where do you use it, what does it return, what do you expect it to return?

Comment: The root of the app is /. @CodeCaster, it's used on various pages which are contained in subfolders located on the root. I expect(ed) it to return the domain + subfolder path as that's how I've come to understand it's use. Seems like I may be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~/ only returns web application root.  If you need to get to http://domain.com/test/test.aspx, and your site's root is http://domain.com, then you need to use ~/test/test.aspx in your code.

Comment: / is site root.  ~/ is web app root.  They can be different.

Comment: In the example here, would `~/test/test.aspx` and `/test/test.aspx` be any different? I guess I'm sort of failing to see the point of the tilde.

Comment: ~/ guarantees you get the application root no matter what folder level the current page is located.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it ~/test/ for root ...